# Want to show Products line in Payment View in ODOO

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odo

I have a Payment view (model is account.payment) in which it displays the bill section in tree view by click on that it redirects to that bill view (model is account.move) and shows tree view for products in it.

i want to show this tree view of products in Payment view. how to do it?

Note: I'm using odoo 15 community  version.

Comment: You need to extends that with code in a custom module, no out of the box solution